# Generating packets from pcap file in C

Tags: c, network-programming, packet, pcap

I've got a bunch of pcap files that contain network packets, I wonder if there's a standard way to regenerate those packets in C from the pcap files. Basically I just want to simulate the traffic captured in the pcap files, so I need to assemble the same packets and send them out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need to decode pcap, you may have a look at libpcap and/or WinPcap. If you need to generate traffic based on pcap files, check out http://wiki.wireshark.org/Tools.

Answer (score 2):

[tcpreplay](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/) is a set of tools that does what you're asking. It's open source so you could look at how it works, and you may even find you can use it without needing to roll your own or modify it.